# Merging Multiple 3D Point Clouds, Reducing Misalignment and Correcting Unusual Height

Tags: satellite, point-cloud, 3d-model, photogrammetry, stereo-imagery

I've been trying to merge two point clouds into a single **uniform** point cloud using the Python package `pyvista`. However, I have encountered an issue that the misalignment between these two point clouds cannot be reduced.

#### Visualizing Point Clouds

The point clouds represent a forest area and were generated using satellite stereo images and satellite photogrammetry. Below are the two original point clouds as well as the merged point cloud:

- **The left point cloud:** There is a long corridor running through the forest, and both sides of the corridor are at a higher elevation than the corridor itself.

  ```
  ds1 = pyvista.read(pcd_path1)
  ds1.plot()
  ```

[image]

- **The right point cloud:** The group of voxels on the top-right corner appears to be unusually high, while the group of voxels on the bottom-left corner seems to be unusually low.

  ```
  ds2 = pyvista.read(pcd_path2)
  ds2.plot()
  ```

[image]

- **The merged point cloud:** After merging the left and right point clouds, there is a noticeable gap between them. Additionally, the issue of extreme height on the top-right corners persists.

  ```
  ds1 = pyvista.read(pcd_path1)
  ds2 = pyvista.read(pcd_path2)
  merged_ds = ds1.merge(ds2)
  merged_ds.plot()
  ```

[image]

#### The Problem

After examining the disparity map, the input stereo images and referring to Google Maps, I have determined that an error occurred during the dense stereo matching step, which is used to create the disparity map that subsequently generates the point cloud. However, I do not have control over fixing the stereo matching algorithm at the moment.

Furthermore, it is common to encounter situations where the stereo matching algorithm does not produce a 100% accurate disparity map, resulting in an imperfect point cloud. Therefore, I believe that post-processing of the point cloud is considered a standard process in the 3D pipeline to address such issues.

Is there a technique available to effectively align the adjacent boundaries of two point clouds while keeping distortions in the point clouds themselves to the minimum?

I think since we are changing the position of voxels in the point cloud, distorting the original point cloud is inevitable. (Maybe the point cloud will look better after being distorted)

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.